# Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] EO

Tags: android, android-emulator

when i was running my emulator device i got an output from emulator,but i received following error:

```
java.io.IOException: EOF
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:659)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:632)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:216)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:378)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:109)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having a similar error. I just got it to work by doing the following steps:

- In a shell or command prompt run: `adb kill-server`
- Unplug the USB cable from the device and plug it back in.
- Open the devices view (Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Devices)
- Click on the device on the android devices view.

Answer (score 5):

This was just happening to me, I clicked the little Recycling Bin icon under logcat in Android Monitor.  Now it's logging again.